# How route a particular vhost on same server with multiple vhosts with haproxy

Tags: apache, routes, backend, haproxy, vhosts

We have:

2HaProxy Servers, called Ha1, Ha2
3 Apache Servers, called S1, S2, S3
2 Web Apps Servers, called: App1, App2

So, i need route 2 apps to same webserver

```
App1.com : Ha1 -> S1.App1.com
App1.com : Ha1 -> S2.App1.com
App1.com : Ha1 -> S3.App1.com

App2.com : Ha2 -> S1.App2.com
App2.com : Ha2 -> S2.App2.com
App2.com : Ha2 -> S3.App2.com
```

I am using Keepalived and this work fine, but the route only call to default vhost from each Apache web server for instance:

S1 default webserver is S1.App1.com
S2 default webserver is S2.App1.com
S3 default webserver is S3.App1.com
So when i call to App2.com haproxy route to SX.App1.com when i'm waiting for SX.App2.com. If the default vhost on Server's is App2 so doesn't work now is the App1.com

```
frontend APP2 App2.com:80
       acl APP2    hdr_end(host) -i App2.com
       use_backend APP2_1 if APP2
backend APP2_1
        option httpclose
        mode http
        option httplog
        balance static-rr
        option httpchk
        option forwardfor

                server S1App2 S1.App2.com:80 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
                server S2App2 S2.App2.com:80 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
                server S3App2 S3.App2.com:80 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
```

I am using HAProxy version 1.5.4, released 2014/09/02

If i call via wget from haproxy server to S1.App2.com working fine so the vhost on S1, S2, S3 it's fine too.

Do you know how i can route calling to particular vhost and no default vhost?

Thanks everyone
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Finally we resolve this situation changing of port each app in servers, for instance:

httpd.conf we wake up Port 8081, 8082, 8083, then in every app of virtualhost we setup with corresponding port as default

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
  DocumentRoot "/path/of/app1/public"
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8082>
  DocumentRoot "/path/of/app2/public"
  ...
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8083>
  DocumentRoot "/path/of/app3/public"
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, every HAproxy cfg

```
        server S1App2 S1.App2.com:8082 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
        server S2App2 S2.App2.com:8082 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
        server S3App2 S3.App2.com:8082 weight 5 maxconn 1000 check
```

So this mode we can call from haproxy as default in every port at every server.